# React "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-state

I am using an API to render data in cards, and each card has a heart icon which when clicked, will change the card's state to favorite. Each card has a corresponding modal (I'm using [material ui modal][1] and ) that has the heart icon as well and I need to do it so that when the heart on the modal is clicked, both the modal and the its corresponding card get the favorite state.

Initially I changed the state in the card and the modal components, and had a piece of code that looked like this:

```
  const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

  const handleIconClick = () => {
    setIsFavorite(!isFavorite);
  };
```

The previous block of code handles the state, and the following is part of the returned html:

```
<CardActions style={favoriteButtonStyle}>
            <IconButton aria-label='add to favorites'>
              {!isFavorite ? (
                <FavoriteBorderIcon onClickCapture={handleIconClick} />
              ) : (
                <FavoriteIcon onClickCapture={} />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
```

Now that I need to match the modal's state with the initial card's state, I have moved the state to the App component and I want to create an array to push the favorite items inside and trying to use the item's id:

```
const [favoriteBeers, setFavoriteBeers] = useState([]);
const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

const handleSetFavorite = id => {
    setFavoriteBeers(
      ...favoriteBeers,
      beers.find(beer => beer.id === id)
    );
    setIsFavorite(true);
    console.log(favoriteBeers);
  };

  const handleRemoveFavorite = id => {
    setFavoriteBeers(favoriteBeers.filter(beer => beer.id !== id));
    setIsFavorite(false);
  };
```

Now when I click the heart on a card all the cards become favorite, and when I click the heart I'm getting "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance".

Comment: I've created a sandbox as well, in case you'd like to test it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-thunder-tifjn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to spread your new value for `favoriteBeers` into an array:

```js
setFavoriteBeers([
  ...favoriteBeers,
  beers.find(beer => beer.id === id)
])
```